# form fields empty when untouched

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm working on a piece of code that is similar to an earlier section. In the earlier section all works well, this has been alot of copy paste but for some reason, when i submit the form after editing, the forms values are empty when the form has not been touched. When i change a value on the form, all is sent well.

Am I missing someting? I know it worked earlier, with the same architecture.

communicatie-form.component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="savePersoneelslidCommunicatie(f)">

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label translate="Personalia.Communicatie.CommunicatieType" class="col-4 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <app-select name="codeCommunicatieType" [selectConfig]="codeCommunicatieTypeSelectConfig" ngModel></app-select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label translate="Personalia.Communicatie.CommunicatieAdres" class="col-4 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="communicatieAdres" ngModel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <label translate="Personalia.Communicatie.Wie" class="col-4 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-8">
            <app-select name="vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau" [selectConfig]="vertrouwelijkheidsNiveauSelectConfig" ngModel></app-select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
      <label translate="Personalia.Adres.Bewijs" class="col-4 col-form-label"></label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <ng-container *ngIf="attestAanwezig">
          <label>{{attest.naam}}</label>&nbsp;
          <button (click)="HaalAttest(attest.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-light"><i class="far fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button (click)="DeleteAttest(attest.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-light"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i></button>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!attestAanwezig">
          <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </ng-container>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right" type="submit" [translate]="submitButtonText"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-global-form-error [error]="serverValidationError" [possibleErrors]="['PersoneelslidNotFound', 'FlowbackAttestMissing']"></app-global-form-error>
  </form>
```

communicatie-form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { convertByteArrayToBlob } from 'src/app/common';
import { CommunicatieVertrouwelijkheidsNiveau } from 'src/app/models';
import { FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie } from 'src/app/models/flowback/flowbackpersoneelslidcommunicatie';
import { FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest } from 'src/app/models/flowback/flowbackpersoneelslidcommunicatieattest';
import { CodeCommunicatieType } from 'src/app/models/selfservice/codecommunicatietype';
import { EloketForm, EnumSelectConfig, ModelSelectConfig, setFormValue } from 'src/app/shared';
import { ValidationBag } from 'src/app/shared/api/models';
import { FlowbackService } from 'src/app/shared/api/services';
import { ConfirmationService } from 'src/app/shared/confirmation.service';

export interface FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm {

  flowbackOpmerking?: string;
  flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest?: FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest;
  attest: any;

  codeCommunicatieType?: CodeCommunicatieType;
  communicatieAdres?: string;
  vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau?: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-communicatie-form',
  templateUrl: './communicatie-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./communicatie-form.component.scss']
})

export class CommunicatieFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm>;

  @Input() serverValidationError: ValidationBag;

  @Input() submitButtonText: string;

  codeCommunicatieTypes: CodeCommunicatieType[];
  codeCommunicatieTypeSelectConfig: ModelSelectConfig<CodeCommunicatieType>;
  public vertrouwelijkheidsNiveauSelectConfig = new EnumSelectConfig(CommunicatieVertrouwelijkheidsNiveau, 'CommunicatieVertrouwelijkheidsNiveau');


  @Input() public set codeCommunicatieTypesInput(v: CodeCommunicatieType[]) {
    if (!v) {
      return;
    }
    this.codeCommunicatieTypeSelectConfig = new ModelSelectConfig(v, _ => _.codeCommunicatieTypeId.toString(), _ => _.omschrijving);
  }

  @Input() set flowBackPersoneelslidCommunicatie(value: FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie) {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('setformvalue in form', value);

    setFormValue(this.FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm, {
      
      codeCommunicatieType: value.codeCommunicatieType,
      communicatieAdres: value.communicatieAdres,
      vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau: value.vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau,
      attest: value.flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest
    });
    console.log('after setformvalue', this.FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm);
    
    if (value.flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest) {
      this.attestAanwezig = true;
      this.attest = new FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest(value.flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest);
    }
  }

  @Output() public flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieChange = new EventEmitter<FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm>();

  fileToUpload: File = null;
  attestAanwezig: boolean = false;
  attest: FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest;

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private flowbackService: FlowbackService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  public async handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
  }

  savePersoneelslidCommunicatie({ valid, value }: EloketForm<FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm>) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log('savepersoneelslidcommunicatie', value, this.FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm);
      value.attest = this.fileToUpload;
      
      this.flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieChange.emit(value);
    }
  }

  async HaalAttest(id: number) {
    let bewijs = await this.flowbackService.GetFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest(id).toPromise();
    let blob = convertByteArrayToBlob(bewijs.data.content, bewijs.data.contentType);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, bewijs.data.fileName.substr(9));

  }

  async DeleteAttest(id: number) {
    const confirmed = await this.confirmationService.promptConfirm('Personalia.Bank.VerwijderenAttestConfirm');
    if (confirmed) {
      var deleted = await this.flowbackService.DeleteFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieAttest(id).toPromise();
      if (deleted) {
        this.attestAanwezig = false;
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

wijzig-communicatie.component.html:

```
<h2 translate="Personalia.Communicatie.WijzigenCommunicatie"></h2>
<app-communicatie-form submitButtonText="Button.Edit" [codeCommunicatieTypesInput]="codeCommunicatieTypes" [serverValidationError]="serverValidationError" [flowBackPersoneelslidCommunicatie]="wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie" [serverValidationError]="serverValidationError" (flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieChange)="onWijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie($event)"></app-communicatie-form>
```

wijzig-communicatie.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiError } from 'src/app/models';
import { CodeCommunicatieType } from 'src/app/models/selfservice/codecommunicatietype';
import { CatchFormError, RouteParamsChange } from 'src/app/shared';
import { CodeTabelService, FlowbackService } from 'src/app/shared/api/services';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/shared/notification.service';
import { FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm } from '../communicatie-form/communicatie-form.component';
import { WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie } from 'src/app/models/flowback/wijzig-flowback-personeelslidCommunicatie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wijzig-communicatie',
  templateUrl: './wijzig-communicatie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wijzig-communicatie.component.scss'],
  providers: [RouteParamsChange]
})
export class WijzigCommunicatieComponent implements OnInit {

  wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie: WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie;
  serverValidationError: ApiError;
  id: number;

  codeCommunicatieTypes: CodeCommunicatieType[];

  constructor(private flowbackService: FlowbackService, private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private routeParamsChange: RouteParamsChange,
    private codeTabelService: CodeTabelService) {
    this.routeParamsChange.watch(this.route, (params) => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.loadData().then(() => this.loadFlowbackCommunicatie());

    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  async loadData() {
    await this.loadCodeCommunicatieTypes();
  }

  async loadFlowbackCommunicatie() {
    const flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie = await this.flowbackService.GetFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieById(this.id).toPromise();
    this.wijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie = new WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie(flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie.data);
    console.log('loadflowbackcommunicatie', flowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie.data);
  }
  

  async loadCodeCommunicatieTypes() {
    this.codeCommunicatieTypes = [];
    const codeCommunicatieTypeDto = await this.codeTabelService.GetCodeCommunicatieTypes().toPromise();
    this.codeCommunicatieTypes = codeCommunicatieTypeDto.map(item => new CodeCommunicatieType(item))
      .sort((a, b) => (b.omschrijving < a.omschrijving ? 1 : -1));

  }

  async onWijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie(flowback: FlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatieForm) {

    console.log('onwijzigflowbackcommunicatie', flowback);
    CatchFormError(this, async () => {

      const updateCommunicatie: WijzigFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie = {
        id: this.id,
        codeCommunicatieTypeId: flowback.codeCommunicatieType.codeCommunicatieTypeId,
        communicatieAdres: flowback.communicatieAdres,
        vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau: flowback.vertrouwelijkheidsNiveau
      };

      let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(updateCommunicatie);
      let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(objJsonStr).toString("base64");

      await this.flowbackService.UpdateFlowbackPersoneelslidCommunicatie({ flowback: objJsonB64, file: flowback.attest as any }).toPromise();
      this.notificationService.showMessage('Personalia.Communicatie.CommunicatieGewijzigd');

      await this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    });
  }

}
```

setFormValue function:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export interface EloketForm<T> extends NgForm {
  value: T;
  setValue: (value: T) => void;
}

export function setFormValue<T>(form: EloketForm<T>, value: T) {
  if (value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      form.setValue(value);
    });
  }
}
```

log output:
[image: log output(1)]

[image: log output(2)]

as you can see, the value parameter comes in as empty in the savePersoneelslidCommunicatie function. Only when i touch a control, all is filled in. The form itself however, has the correct values when logged.